# .htaccess configuration for OJS 2.4.8-2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ojs

Im having trouble to remove index.php on a OJS instalation using Apache 2.4

I have set "restful_urls" to "On" on OJS.
And my htaccess is the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And im getting this errors on the log when i open the page

```
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678593 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/revista
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678834 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/revista -> index.php/revista
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678852 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/revista'
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678936 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] rewrite 'index.php/revista' -> 'index.php/index.php/revista'
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678957 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/index.php/revista -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/revista
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678975 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/revista -> /index.php/index.php/revista
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678990 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/revista [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679134 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/revista
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679157 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/revista -> index.php/index.php/revista
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679222 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/index.php/revista'
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679268 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] rewrite 'index.php/index.php/revista' -> 'index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679289 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679306 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679320 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/index.php/revista [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679425 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679447 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679460 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679485 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] rewrite 'index.php/index.php/index.php/revista' -> 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679501 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679518 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
    [Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679567 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Any advice?